# Create access point (uap0) on debian 7(arm) - not found?

Tags: debian, arm

I'm working with a fanless PC that has an ARM chipset, 2 eth plugs and a wifi card (among other things). If I install debian 6 on it all three network interfaces are available at boot time. Today I tried to install debian 7 and had numerous errors indicating that the wireless card isn't supported.

```
uap0: error fetching interface information: Device not found
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device
uap0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
uap0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
No such device
ERR:UAPHOSTCMD is not supported by uap0
ERR:Command sending failed!
No such device
ERR:UAPHOSTCMD is not supported by uap0
ERR:Command sending failed!
```

I've tried comparing the kernel module list to the working system but there are too many other differences to make something obvious enough (to me) stand out.

How would I get started debugging this problem?

Comment: Is this a Sheevaplug/Guruplug or related?

Comment: Dreamplug to be precise. Is there a better forum?

Comment: I can help you I believe in a bit when I can hook my Guruplug up, if no one else beats me to this.  Basically though, if you have a `wlan0` interface, it loaded the wrong firmware for the `libertas` driver and I would think that is it.